# React Unit test function vs ArrowFunction

Tags: reactjs, testing, enzyme

I have simple page with two divs. Background color of the second div depends on state of the active property. If *active* is true then it should use *.active* class from CSS file, otherwise use *.two* style.

I wrote unit test for this scenario to check if the style of the second div has been changed after state was changed.

I realized one thing, that when i execute *style()* function to get correct style name, unit test is not working and my style on second div is not updated. But when i execute *style* as an arrow function everything works. Do any of you know, why this happens? whats the problem with *normal* call of function? why render() is not called?

**Arrow function console output (expected)**

```
console.log src/containers/Example/Example.test.js:18
  false
console.log src/containers/Example/Example.test.js:19
  two
console.log src/containers/Example/Example.test.js:21
  true
console.log src/containers/Example/Example.test.js:22
  active
```

**Normal function (wrong output)**

```
console.log src/containers/Example/Example.test.js:18
  false
console.log src/containers/Example/Example.test.js:19
  two
console.log src/containers/Example/Example.test.js:21
  true
console.log src/containers/Example/Example.test.js:22
  two
```

**Component with Arrow function**

When you replace *() => this.style()* by *this.style()* unit test will fail.

```js
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import styles from './Example.module.css';

class Example extends Component {

  state = {
    active: false
  };

  active = () => {
    this.setState({active: !this.state.active});
  };

  style = () => {
    return this.state.active ? styles.active : styles.two;
  };

  render() {
    return (
        <div>
          <div onClick={() => this.active()} className={styles.one}/>
          <div className={() => this.style()}/>
        </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Example;
```

**Unit test for Component**

```js
import React from 'react';
import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16';
import {configure, mount} from 'enzyme';
import styles from './Example.module.css';

import Example from './Example';

configure({adapter: new Adapter()});

let component;

beforeEach(() => {
  component = mount(<Example/>);
});

it('description', () => {
  let two = component.find('div').at(2);
  console.log(component.state().active);
  console.log(two.props()["className"]());
  component.setState({active: true});
  console.log(component.state().active);
  console.log(two.props()["className"]());
});
```

For second case *this.style()* you need to slightly modify console output

- replace this *console.log(two.props()["className"]);* by this *console.log(two.props()"className");*
- replace this *console.log(two.props()["className"]);* by this *console.log(two.props()"className");*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem isn't specific to unit testing but to the usage of functions in JavaScript. It would be applicable to production application as well.

`onClick` prop is expected to be a function. `() => this.style()` expression is a function. `this.style()` is the result of calling `style` method, a string.

Since `style` method is already bound to component instance (it's an arrow), it doesn't need to be wrapped with another arrow. It should be:

```
<div className={this.style}/>
```